# CSS font-face doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts

I have a problem with @font-face. I followed different solutions but none of them worked. If someone can give me any tips I would aprecciate.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Neris';
    src: url('indexFiles/neris_thin.otf');
}
body {
    border:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Neris';
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: You should check your folder path. And be sure you haven't left any capital letter in the font name

Comment: 1) Is that class selector for `.body` intentional? If so, why do you have an element with the class `body`?  2) You should really use .woff files, not .otf.

Comment: Give us a link to your page. Are you using a browser that needs a format other than otf? Is your path correct?

Comment: I'm using firefox localy, nevermind de body class. going to try with no caps

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Neris';
  src: url(indexFiles/Neris_thin.otf);  //Is path correct? Maybe use absolute.
}
```

The @font-face rule is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support the WOFF (Web Open Font Format) font.

Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera also support fonts of type TTF (True Type Fonts) and OTF (OpenType Fonts).

Chrome, Safari and Opera also support SVG fonts/shapes.

Internet Explorer also supports EOT (Embedded OpenType) fonts.

Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the @font-face rule.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: try the code above with the absolute url (`http://www.yoursite.com/indexFiles/Neris_thin.otf`) and remove my comment. Notice there is no quote around the URL in my example. This won't work on IE, since it's .otf